# use C++ RTTI in template function ,aCC compiler give compile error

Tags: c++, templates, rtti

code as follow:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<occi.h>
using namespace std; using namespace oracle::occi;

template<class T> void print(T  val) {
    if (typeid(val).name()==typeid((int)1).name())
    {
        val+=2;
    }
    else if (typeid(val).name()==typeid((string())).name())
    {
        val+="string";
    }
    cout<<val<<endl; }

int main() {
    int a=100;
    string str="abcdef";
    print(str);     
    print(a);
    return 0; 
}
```

the error message of aCC compiler as follow:

```
aCC -AA  +DD64 -mt   -g -D_DEBUG_ -I/oracle/app1/oracle/product/9.2/rdbms/demo  -I/oracle/app1/oracle/product/9.2/rdbms/public -I/oracle/app1/oracle/product/9.2/plsql/public  -I/oracle/app1/oracle/product/9.2/network/public   -c test4.cpp
Error 203: "test4.cpp", line 16 # Cannot assign 'int' with 'const char *'.

            val+="string";
            ^^^^^^^^

Error 445: "test4.cpp", line 21 # Cannot recover from earlier errors.
    int main()
    ^^^^^^^^^^
*** Error exit code 2

Stop.
```

Comment: You are getting a compile error because your function wants `val` to be an `int` and a `string` at the same time. Template specialization would solve this problem easily, but that's not the topic of your question.

Comment: You should compare the `type_info` objects themselves, rather than the result of `name()` - there's no guarantee that `name()` returns the same result for different objects describing the same type. (Of course, you shouldn't use RTTI at all here, since the types are known at compile time).

Answer (score 2):

You should use template specialization to achieve this:

```
/* template declaration - no definition (you can add a definition as default
   for unknown types if you want)
 */
template<class T> void print(T  val);

// This will be used if the parameter is of type int
template<>
void print<int>(int val) {
    val += 2;
    cout << val << endl;
}

// This will be used if the parameter is of type string
template<>
void print<std::string>(std::string val) {\
    val += "string";
    cout << val << endl;
}
```

Alternatively, you can just write overloads for each type you want to handle:

```
// This will be used if the parameter is of type int
void print(int val) {
    val += 2;
    cout << val << endl;
}

// This will be used if the parameter is of type string
void print(std::string val) {\
    val += "string";
    cout << val << endl;
}
```

The template-approach offers the advantage that you can define a default-implementation that handles all types for which you have not written an implementation by hand. If you do not require that, the overload-approach is simpler and safer.

Comment: This code does not need to have templates to work properly; simple overloading will work fine.

Comment: No need to use a function template, two overloads would be better.

Comment: Template functions specialisations [are evil](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

Comment: I don't see the need to downvote this. I think template specialization is actually better in this case since the OP is using `cout << val`. Otherwise you would have to write a separate overload for every type you want to pass to the function.

Comment: @LucTouraille: You are right - I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: But there are many datatypes. There will be many "print" need to be coding,if I follow this ways!

Comment: @Marlon: I didn't downvote and you are right, the two overloads are not equivalent to the code posted by the OP. A closer solution would be `template <typename T> void print(T val) { doPrint(val); cout << val << endl; } template <typename T> void doPrint(T & val) {} void doPrint(int & val) { val += 2; } void doPrint(string & val) { val += "string"; }`

Comment: @user1087287: If you do this your way, you will have many `if`-statements - thats not better.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to encapsulate the part of your function that depends on the datatype in its own function. This way, you will be able to provide overloads for each type that you need to handle in a particular way:

```
template <typename T>
void print(T val) 
{
    doPrint(val);
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
}

// default case
template <typename T>
void doPrint(T & val)
{}

// int case
void doPrint(int & val)
{
    val += 2;
}

// string case
void doPrint(std::string & val)
{
    val += "string";
}

int main()
{
    print(42);                 // outputs 44
    print(std::string("foo")); // outputs foostring
    print(12.);                // outputs 12
    print("bar");              // outputs bar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an implementation of print for each type that you are trying to pass-in.  This code violates the KISS principle due to the typeid checks.